# How to have the cp command create any necessary folders for copying a file to a destination

Tags: linux, bash, cp

When copying a file using `cp` to a folder that may or may not exist, how do I get `cp` to create the folder if necessary? Here is what I have tried:

```
[root@file nutch-0.9]# cp -f urls-resume /nosuchdirectory/hi.txt
cp: cannot create regular file `/nosuchdirectory/hi.txt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: @nelaar The age of the question is a secondary concern; the quality and breadth of the answers should be the deciding factor. I don't have a strong preference either way, but I don't think it's worth the effort at this point to turn around the duplicate relationship. If you think otherwise, please offer a rationale (perhaps on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ for proper visibility and process).

Comment: Looked for the same thing and could not find my answer below so will post how I ended up doing this: `dirname "/nosuchdirectory/hi.txt" | while read path;do mkdir -p "$path"; done && cp -f urls-resume /nosuchdirectory/hi.txt`

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers

Answer (score 396):

To expand upon [Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947969/4298200), the only reliable way to do this would be to combine `mkdir` and `cp`:

```
mkdir -p /foo/bar && cp myfile "$_"
```

As an aside, when you only need to create a single directory in an existing hierarchy, `rsync` can do it in one operation.  I'm quite a fan of `rsync` as a much more versatile `cp` replacement, in fact:

```
rsync -a myfile /foo/bar/ # works if /foo exists but /foo/bar doesn't.  bar is created.
```

Comment: It's mentioned in the above answer but I'd like to re-emphasize it (after a few minutes wasted because of not noticing the fine print): The `rsync` command above is *not* equivalent to the `mkdir/cp` command above. It just creates a single level of folder. Actually I'm not sure when it can be useful.

Comment: Also, for anyone wondering about the `-p` argument to `mkdir`, it's documented in the POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html and causes intermediate pathname components to be created (i.e. lets you `mkdir foo/bar/baz` even if `foo` or `bar` don't already exist).

Comment: `"$_"` is a `bash variable` - [LINK FOR MORE INFO](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-shell-special-parameters/#comments).

Comment: Some more info about the bash variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/3982562

Comment: @PengheGeng : yes, this rsync command can only create one level of folders, but rsync has options to create them all, or only some. [rsync: how can I configure it to create target directory on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/)

Comment: what a chore.. this should be implemented for `cp`

Comment: rsync is so powerful that I suggest dry-run option. "rsync --dry-run -av myfile /foo/bar/".

Comment: Downvote:  For those looking to automate, the `cp --parents` and `rarchive` answers may likely be better. This is because the `mkdir -p` part of this answer takes just a directory, requiring you to script an extra step to parse the directory out from the full filename.

Answer (score 134):

I didn't know you could do that with cp.

You can do it with mkdir ..

```
mkdir -p /var/path/to/your/dir
```

**EDIT** 
See lhunath's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14085147/102616) for incorporating cp.

Comment: cp(1) doesn't.  mkdir -p /foo/bar && cp myfile "$_" is indeed the only way to do this reliably.

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34608146/2007944

Comment: This anwser should not be here. The question was regarding `cp` not `mkdir` ...

Comment: Hi @KarlMorrison this is an 8 year old question & answer. I also stated that it was for mkdir and not cp.

Comment: @Christian I know, it is 2017 and this is the answer directly under the question, which it shouldn't be. I know that you stated that, however people like me actually looking for an answer regarding the `cp` command is met with answers like this which have nothing to do with `cp` prolonging my search for a correct answer. The only answer here which is accurate is https://stackoverflow.com/a/947971/1137669 he states that `cp` cannot do it. No one else (including yourself) state that it is not possible with `cp`.

Comment: Doesn't `cp --parents {}` make it done now?

Comment: For those looking to automate, the `cp --parents` and `rarchive` answers may likely be better. This is because the `mkdir -p` part of this answer takes just a directory, requiring you to script an extra step to parse the directory out from the full filename.

Answer (score 42):

One can also use the command `find`:

```
find ./ -depth -print | cpio -pvd newdirpathname
```

Comment: this is by far the best answer because it allows you to create directories without previously needing to know their full path.

Answer (score 36):

```
 mkdir -p `dirname /nosuchdirectory/hi.txt` && cp -r urls-resume /nosuchdirectory/hi.txt
```

Answer (score 23):

There is no such option. What you can do is to run *mkdir -p* before copying the file

I made a *very cool* script you can use to copy files in locations that doesn't exist

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$2"
fi
cp -R "$1" "$2"
```

Now just save it, give it permissions and run it using

```
./cp-improved SOURCE DEST
```

I put -R option but it's just a draft, I know it can be and you will improve it in many ways. Hope it helps you

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions, please.  Or you'll suffer bugs introduced by wordsplitting and pathname expansion.  Put "" around all your $foo's.

Comment: That will lead to weird results if someone tries to rename the file while coping: `cp-improved /foo/file.jpg /bar/file.jpg.bak`. I will end up with `/bar/file.jpg.bak/file.jpg` regardless if `bar` exists or not

Answer (score 9):

rsync is work!

```
#file:
rsync -aqz _vimrc ~/.vimrc

#directory:
rsync -aqz _vim/ ~/.vim
```

Comment: doesnt work .. rsync will only create one directory for you.

Answer (score -9):

```
cp -Rvn /source/path/* /destination/path/
cp: /destination/path/any.zip: No such file or directory
```

It will create no existing paths in destination, if path have a source file inside.
This dont create empty directories.

A moment ago i've seen xxxxxxxx: No such file or directory, because i run out of free space. without error message.

with ditto:

```
ditto -V /source/path/* /destination/path
ditto: /destination/path/any.zip: No space left on device
```

once freed space `cp -Rvn /source/path/* /destination/path/` works as expected