# Unix - create path of folders and file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I know you can do `mkdir` to create a directory and `touch` to create a file, but is there no way to do both operations in one go?

i.e. if I want to do the below when the folder `other` does not exist:

```
cp /my/long/path/here/thing.txt /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
```

Error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt': No such file or directory
```

Has anyone come up with a function as a workaround for this?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529946/linux-copy-and-create-destination-dir-if-it-does-not-exist

Comment: If it's essential that the creation of the file and its directory be atomic, you would have to write a file system that offers this operation. It's not possible with the standard Linux file systems.

Comment: @toop I understand that this question is now a year and a half old, but several answers were recently merged into this. If you need to this type of thing very often, you may find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19288855/119527) useful. (I'd argue more useful than the accepted answer, but I'm not begging for rep here :-) )

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722721/29182

Comment: @tdammers Q:"How do I do X?" A:"Here's how to do Y"

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Use `&&` to combine two commands in one shell line:

```
COMMAND1 && COMMAND2
mkdir -p /my/other/path/here/ && touch /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
```

Note: Previously I recommended usage of `;` to separate the two commands but as pointed out by @trysis it's probably better to use `&&` in most situations because in case `COMMAND1` fails `COMMAND2` won't be executed either. (Otherwise this might lead to issues you might not have been expecting.)

Comment: Probably better to use `&&`, as with `;`, if the first command fails, the second command will still run (and fail, too, as that directory does not exist yet). With `&&` if the first command fails, the second command does not run.

Comment: A short cut for the code example can be: `mkdir -p /my/other/path/here && touch $_/cpredthing.txt`. The `$_` expands to essentially the "last argument in the last command executed".

Comment: @Sgnl yours is arguably the correct answer. It is not just cleaner, it is less error-prone.

Comment: I really wish `touch` took a `-p` parameter like `mkdir` does.

Answer (score 99):

You need to make all of the parent directories first.

```
FILE=./base/data/sounds/effects/camera_click.ogg

mkdir -p "$(dirname "$FILE")" && touch "$FILE"
```

---

If you want to get creative, you can [make a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter):

```
mktouch() {
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "Missing argument";
        return 1;
    fi

    for f in "$@"; do
        mkdir -p -- "$(dirname -- "$f")"
        touch -- "$f"
    done
}
```

And then use it like any other command:

```
mktouch ./base/data/sounds/effects/camera_click.ogg ./some/other/file
```

Comment: Changed it to use `&&` - How's that?

Comment: Is bash supporting return in functions?

Comment: @BЈовић [Yes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html). (I do try to test things before I post them.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Are you sure that you tested it?  I tried `supertouch "/tmp/abc/def ghi/jkl mno.txt"` and it failed.  All the commands `dirname`, `mkdir`, and `touch` gave erros.

Comment: @devnull Apparently not well enough. Damn your spaces :-) Fixed.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Good to see that you've quoted the arguments.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I like the script very much, but suggest the name "mktouch" - added to my .profile - Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyIglehart I like it. `mktouch` it is.

Answer (score 32):

Do it with /usr/bin/install:

```
install -D /my/long/path/here/thing.txt /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
```

when you don't have a source file:

```
install -D <(echo 1) /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
```

Comment: I am surprised this gem tool is largely ignored - man install - will show that install is a better solution.

Comment: You can also use `-D /dev/null`, which is easier for me to remember.

Comment: This creates **executables** by default. You would need the `-m` option to set other file modes.

Answer (score 19):

This is what I would do:

`mkdir -p /my/other/path/here && touch $_/cpredthing.txt`

Here, the `$_` is a variable that represents the last argument to the previous command that we executed in line.

As always if you want to see what the output might be, you can test it by using the `echo` command, like so:

`echo mkdir -p /code/temp/other/path/here && echo touch $_/cpredthing.txt`

Which outputs as:

```
mkdir -p /code/temp/other/path/here
touch /code/temp/other/path/here/cpredthing.txt
```

As a bonus, you could write multiple files at once using brace expansion, for example:

```
mkdir -p /code/temp/other/path/here &&
touch $_/{cpredthing.txt,anotherfile,somescript.sh}
```

Again, totally testable with `echo`:

```
mkdir -p /code/temp/other/path/here
touch /code/temp/other/path/here/cpredthing.txt /code/temp/other/path/here/anotherfile /code/temp/other/path/here/somescript.sh
```

Answer (score 14):

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in "$@"; do mkdir -p "$(dirname "$f")"; done
touch "$@"
```

Comment: An anonymous user suggested (via edit) to use `dirname -z "$@" | xargs -0 mkdir -p` instead, for performance's sake. (Stop lurking, and join, for Pete's sake! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

you can do it in two steps:

```
mkdir -p /my/other/path/here/
touch /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

as I saw and test in a unix forum this solves the problem

```
ptouch() {
    for p in "$@"; do
        _dir="$(dirname -- "$p")"
        [ -d "$_dir" ] || mkdir -p -- "$_dir"
    touch -- "$p"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ ! -d /my/other ]
then
   mkdir /my/other/path/here
   cp /my/long/path/here/thing.txt /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for `if then` statements...
you can do it on a single line usign `;`

```
mkdir -p /my/other/path/here;cp /my/long/path/here/thing.txt /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
```

-- or on two lines --

```
mkdir -p /my/other/path/here
cp /my/long/path/here/thing.txt /my/other/path/here/cpedthing.txt
```

-- the `-p` prevents error returns if the directory already exists (which is what I came here looking for :))

Answer (score 1):

In the special (but not uncommon) case where you are trying to recreate the same directory hierarchy, `cp --parents` can be useful.

For example if `/my/long` contains the source files, and `my/other` already exists, you can do this:

```
cd /my/long
cp --parents path/here/thing.txt /my/other
```

Answer (score -4):

if you want simple with only 1 param snippet :

```
rm -rf /abs/path/to/file;  #prevent cases when old file was a folder
mkdir -p /abs/path/to/file; #make it fist as a dir
rm -rf /abs/path/to/file; #remove the leaf of the dir preserving parents 
touch /abs/path/to/file; #create the actual file
```

Comment: If you want to simply get rid of the last few hours'† work, gratitiously throw around some `rm -rf` commands. — †That is, _hours_, assuming you adhere to a sensible version control / backup policy... otherwise, it might well be months.

Comment: `rm -rf` should never be suggested without proper explanation and warnings.