# is there any single command to create a file with missing directory structure

Tags: shell, unix

Is there any single command to create a file with missing directory structure?

Suppose I have a variable `LOG_STORAGE_PATH=/var/log/app-log/access.log` in my shell script and I dont know if `app-log` directory and `access.log` file is present.

Is there a single command, like `mkdir -p </some/random/path>` which creates all intermediate directories if not present, to create a file with missing directories in between.

This would have been accomplished with the help of

```
LOG_STORAGE_PATH=/var/log/app-log/
ACCESS_LOG_FILE=access.log
ACCESS_LOG_FILE_PATH=${LOG_STORAGE_PATH}/${ACCESS_LOG_FILE}
if [ ! -d ${LOG_STORAGE_PATH} ]
then
    mkdir -p ${LOG_STORAGE_PATH}
fi  
if [ ! -f ${ACCESS_LOG_FILE_PATH} ]
then
    touch ${ACCESS_LOG_FILE_PATH}
fi
```

I was looking for `touch` command with same functionality as `mkdir -p`, but its not present.

It would have been very useful if we had a `touch -p /var/log/app-log/access.log` command which can create a file along with missing directories, or if directories are present then just create the file or even if directories and file both present then just update the `access time` of the file.

Just for a thought, maybe we wouldn't have to use `if [ ! -f <some file> ]` or `if [ ! -d <some dir path> ]` in our scripts, we could have directly used `touch -p ${ACCESS_LOG_FILE_PATH}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix - create path of folders and file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452935/unix-create-path-of-folders-and-file)

Comment: You don't need to test with `-d` and `-f`. Just use `mkdir -p` and `touch`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot able to do this with single command in unix. To do this you need two commands (mkdir and  touch).