# How to get path from where shell file was run from Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have created a custom script for creating a file inside the directory.
/mnt/c/Users/username/Documents/mkfile.sh (I am using the windows subsystem for Linux)

```
dir_str=$1
dir_arr=($(echo $dir_str | tr "[\\\/]" "\n"))
dir_path=""
file_name=""

for i in "${!dir_arr[@]}"
do 
  dirArrLen=${#dir_arr[@]}
  if [ $(($i+1)) -ge $dirArrLen ] 
  then
    sudo touch "${dir_path}/${dir_arr[$i]}"
    file_name=${dir_arr[$i]}
    # echo "${dir_path}/${dir_arr[$i]}"
  elif [ $(($i+1)) -eq 1 ]
  then
    # to avoid starting slash
    sudo mkdir "${dir_arr[$i]}"
    dir_path=${dir_arr[$i]}
    # echo $dir_path
  else
    sudo mkdir "${dir_path}/${dir_arr[$i]}"
    # echo "${dir_path}/${dir_arr[$i]}"
    dir_path="${dir_path}/${dir_arr[$i]}"
  fi
done
echo "File ${file_name} has been created successfully in ${dir_path}"
```

when this is executed inside the path(/mnt/c/Users/username/Documents/) where mkfile shell script file is present at now it creates a file successfully.
ex:

> **Input :**

```
/mnt/c/Users/username/Documents$./mkfile.sh hello/world/new.txt
```

> **Output:**
> It creates a new.txt file inside like :
> /mnt/c/Users/username/Documents/hello/world/new.txt

```
File new.txt has been created successfully in hello/world
```

but when I move the file to the home directory add it to alias in `~/.bashrc` file like(To make it as a custom shell command)

```
alias mkfile="~/mkfile.sh"
```

This shell script is not working(I think this is trying to create a file in the home directory instead
from where it was called), ex:

```
username@DESKTOP-SELKMGP:/mnt/c/Users/username/Documents/$ mkfile hello/world/new.txt
```

does not create any directory/file inside documents.

**Question:**

**Inside `mkfile.sh` file situated in the home directory is there any way to capture the path of the directory from where the command was entered,**

ex:

**Input :**

```
/mnt/c/Users/username/Documents$ mkfile hello/world/new.txt
```

**Expected :**
Inside ~/mkfile.sh situated in home directory I want to get:
/mnt/c/Users/username/Documents/

I tried `pwd` but that outputs the home directory path instead of the path from where the command was entered
and also `realpath $0` did not work

Comment: `mkfile.sh` is over-elaborate, and doesn't always work.  (For instance, it fails with paths that contain spaces (e.g. `hello/a b/c.txt`).)  The oneliner `mkdir --parents -- "$(dirname -- "$1")" && touch -- "$1"` is much more reliable.  There are other ways to do it.  See [mkdir -p for files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63098/264812), [Unix - create path of folders and file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9452935/4154375), and [One command to create a directory and file inside it linux command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17986615/4154375)

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestions, but I wanted to just know if there were any ways to accept the path from which the command was executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what your problem is, I think you should set alias as below:

```
alias mkfile="~/mkfile.sh $(pwd)"
```

this command sent full path of where it was called to script as `dir_str`

try this one, I hope this helps.

Comment: I modified first few lines and added some `dir_str=$2
dir_arr=($(echo $dir_str | tr "[\\\/]" "\n"))
dir_path=""
cd ~
cd $1`  and modified ~/.bashrc file like as you said and ran `source ~/.bashrc` to refresh and now it works fine.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I was able to help, please give 'Up Flag' to my answer. thanks

Comment: I got reputation from your upvote to upvote thanks.