# Create path when copying a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I know there is a thread on this site for creating a directory when using `cp` but my question is a little different.
I want to copy a file in a new destination in linux, but some part of the path might not exist and I wanted to know whether it is possible to create that path without separating directory name from file name, for example, imagine I have a variable that contains the prefix for new files `$prefixdir` and I want every file to be copied in that location.

```
prefixdir=/home/akj/newpath
list="$(ls /somelocation...)"
for l in $list
do
   cp -v $l "$prefixdir$l"
done
```

From the example it is obvious that there can be some directories that don't exist under new location and because of file names I can't use `mkdir "$prefixdir$l"`. I know I can separate file name from directory name and then use `mkdir` but I was wondering if there were an elegant way to do that.

EDIT:

To just clarify my question imagine I want to copy `/lib/tt/test.so` and my `$prefixdir` is `/home/akj/`. Also imagine that `lib/tt` doesn't exist, so my `cp` command would fail. I also can't use `mkdir -p` because of `test.so` in the path.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `mkdir -p`?

Comment: Or maybe `mkdir -p \`dirname $prefixdir$l\` `?

Comment: @JuliusDavies, that's the right idea, but quotes are required around the variables.

Comment: @akj88, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), any filenames with spaces will cause the for-loop to split the filenames. You want `for file in /somelocation/.../*; do`

Comment: @glenn jackman Thanks, I won't, but that is just to explain my problem.

Comment: Julius has your answer: `mkdir -p "$(dirname "$prefixdir$l")" && cp ...`

Comment: You are looking for   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529946/linux-copy-and-create-destination-dir-if-it-does-not-exist

Comment: @glenn jackman Sorry I just read the first answer, now I read others an found the solution, also the one  Julius Davies mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Gnu coreutils (normally you will on linux), you can use:

```
install -m 0644 -D source_file dest_filename
```

which automatically creates necessary directories.

The `-m 0644` flag sets the permissions of the new file to 0644 (`rw-r--r--`); you need that because the default is to set the permissions to `rxwr-xr-x` (on the assumption that the file should be executable, since that's the usual use case) rather than copying the permissions of the original file.