# Copy bulk files to another destination using a given prefix in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to copy all the files newer than another one from their original location `/lib/` into another destination `/dest/lib/`

To identify these files I simply use:

```
$ cd /lib/
$ find . -newer foobar
./foo/bar.py
./bar/foo/bar/foo.py
...
```

Unfortunately I cannot simply use this command because `cp` does not know how to create folders on the fly.

So I used this command:

```
find /foo -type f -newer foobar | \
    xargs -n1 -I% sh -c 'mkdir -vp `dirname /dest/%` && cp -v % /dest/%'
```

This looks very complicated and is incredibly slow. Is there a better solution?

Comment: [You can use `cp --parents`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722721/1983854)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tar` for this, for example, let's you have directory '1',
and you want copy something to directory '2', then:

```
cd 1
tar -c a.txt 3/b.txt | tar -x -C ../2
```

also you can use `rsync` it works with local paths