# Copy and create a directory with date timestamp where it does not exist

Tags: linux, shell, unix, mkdir, cp

**Background:**

I have a Jenkins task that is executing and before running i want to take a copy of a folder and move it to another directory which does not exist and is a dynamic timestamp.

For the purposes of this argument i am not able to create variables to store anything, it must be accomplished without them. I have seen this other question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529946/linux-copy-and-create-destination-dir-if-it-does-not-exist), and this seems to confirm the approach i am going for.

**Question:**

What is the best way to achieve this for Linux/Unix?

I have an idea below but i want to check if this is the best approach or not. It starts by making the directory `mkdir -p` with the location of the directory `/tmp/backup/myapp/` and the date timestamp as the final folder name `$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`, it then calls a recursive copy `cp -r` and provides the source directory to be copied `/var/www/html/myapp` and then passes in the original location url as the destination `$_`

**Suggested Answer**

```
mkdir -p /tmp/backup/myapp/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) && cp -r /var/www/html/myapp $_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems correct to me, just some minor fix:

```
mkdir -p "/tmp/backup/myapp/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)" && cp -a "/var/www/html/myapp" "$_"
```

Use double quotes to avoid space problems (in your example is not needed but better be prudent).

Use `cp -a` to copy directories. It works as `-r|-R` but in addiction it always preserves symlinks and metadata, such as timestamps and ownership, of the files.