# Move folder but keep preceding structure using shell in CENTOS6.8

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following folder structure:

```
parent
├── child1
├── child2
└── child3
    └── childofchild
        └── childofchildofchild
            └── file.txt
```

I want to move childofchildofchild into a new folder, but keep the structure preceding it so the end result would be the following:

```
newfolder
└── child3
    └── childofchild
        └── childofchildofchild
            └── file.txt
```

Edit: I need the files removed from the original folder, not duplicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: copy and create destination dir if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529946/linux-copy-and-create-destination-dir-if-it-does-not-exist)

Comment: So you want parent/child3/childofchild/foo to remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what are you trying to do, but something as ...?

```
mkdir parent/newfolder && mv parent/child3 parent/newfolder
```

I think I'm missing something tho

Comment: I guess this works. I'm generating a script to do this with over 2000 folders, so I was thinking of a single line solution, this might be an obvious solution I overlooked

Comment: Glad it helped!