# Copy files to destination and create destination if does not exist

Tags: linux, zsh

I am writing a bash script to copy **ONE** or **MORE THAN ONE** or **ALL** files to a destination, and create the destination if it does not exist.

I have already gone through this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529946/linux-copy-and-create-destination-dir-if-it-does-not-exist/61261945#61261945%27) but it does not complete my requirements.

My code (Which does not work for idk what reasons):

```
# copy files and make a directory if does not exist
mkcp() {
    # last argument is destination
    dir="${@: -1}"
    # create directory if does not exist
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    # loop over all arguments
    for file in "$@"
    do
        # if file is last argument (directory) then break loop
        if [ "$file" == "$dir" ]; then
            break
        fi
        # else keep copying files
        cp -R "$file" "$dir"
    done
}
```

I want all these commands to be working:

```
# copies "text.txt" to "testdir" (testdir may or may not exist so it must be created first)
$ mkcp test.txt ~/desktop/testdir

# copies "test1.txt" and "test2.txt" to "testdir" (conditions are same)
$ mkcp test1.txt test2.txt ~/desktop/testdir

# copies "all files" to "testdir" (conditions are same)
$ mkcp * ~/desktop/testdir
```

If there's any other solution that can complete my requirements, I am okay with it too.

Note: The `mkcp` function is stored in `.zshrc`.

Comment: Clearly, `mkdir -p dir` should be `mkdir -p "$dir"`.  Similar problems are in `if [ file == dir ]; then` and `cp -R "$file" dir`.  Variables must be prefixed with a `$` and  should be surrounded by quotes unless you know exactly why not.

Comment: Consider whether the GNU-style `cp` interface with `-t target-dir` as a way to specify the target directory would be better.  It is very useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry I am new to bash. I made all the changes you mentioned, now I am getting the error `mkcp:9: = not found`. It would be great if you write the correct script in answer.

Comment: Wait, .zshrc? Well this is not a bash question at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that the last argument must be a directory, and if no such directory exists, it should be created. In zsh, I would do it like this:

```
mkcp() {
  local destdir=$@[-1]
  if [[ -f $destdir ]]
  then
    echo Missing destination directory 2>&1 
    return 1
  else
    mkdir -p $destdir
    if [[ -d $destdir ]]
    then
      cp "$@"
    else
      echo Can not create $destdir
      return 1
    fi
  fi
}
```

The problem is not the copying (the plain `cp` command can do it and no loop is needed), so the focus here is on error checking.

Note that with my approach, switches can be passed implicitly to `cp`, for instance

```
mkcp -r foo bar baz
```

copies recursively the subdirectories too, and

```
mkcp -rv foo bar baz
```

is in addition printing the names of the files which are copied.

Comment: This worked so smoothly, thanks.

Comment: Also, can you explain `-d` and `-f` options?

Comment: `-d` is not an option. It is an operator for the `[[ ... ]]` command to test whether the argument is  a directory. Similarily, `-f` tests whether the argument is a plain file. Have a look at the section titled  _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS_  in _man zshall_.

Comment: D'oh! `cp "$@"` -- in hindsight, how obvious! Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

I added this bash answer before I realized this is a zsh question. Not deleting it in hopes others find it useful.

---

You can take a sublist of the positional arguments using the `${var:offset:length}` expansion. See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual.

Perhaps this:

```sh
mkcp() {
    local dir="${@: -1}"

    mkdir -p "$dir"

    for file in "${@:0:$#}"     # all but last
    do
        cp -vR "$file" "$dir"
    done
}
```

In fact, it can be simpler, assuming you have GNU cp with the `-t` option:

```sh
mkcp() {
    local dir="${@: -1}"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    cp -t "$dir" -vR "${@:0:$#}"
}
```

I added cp's `-v` option for extra verbosity, so you can see what files are being copied.

Comment: The tag says zsh; the text says bash.  The question is self-inconsistent. 

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my command, that's why it was not working. But now I fixed it and it's working smoothly. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : You are right, but since the OP further down explains that he is going to put this function into .zshrc, I assume that his mentioning of _bash_ is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the main changes I suggest should look like:

```
mkcp() {
    # last argument is destination
    dir="${@: -1}"
    # create directory if does not exist
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    # loop over all arguments
    for file in "$@"
    do
        # if file is last argument (directory) then break loop
        if [ "$file" == "$dir" ]; then
            break
        fi
        # else keep copying files
        cp -R "$file" "$dir"
    done
}
```

I'm not clear how you'd get the error message `mkcp:9: = not found`; to debug that, I'd need to see your modified code.  OTOH, I'm not convinced that debugging that is going to be particularly constructive.

Comment: I've edited my question with the changes mentioned by you, it's the same code in your answer, and still getting this error. This question (505 upvotes) is already answered but it's for a single file. It can be useful if someone wants to copy multiple files at once.

Comment: @VishwaMittar, you have `if [ file == "$dir" ]`, this answer correctly has `if [ "$file" == "$dir" ]`

Comment: @glennjackman I just realized it. Thanks for the correction tho.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this command

```
# copies "all files" to "testdir" (conditions are same)
$ mkcp * ~/desktop/testdir
```

You're passing a string "*" as command to a custom function, so when you send
*mkcp * you're actually saying "cp -R * /path" where * is just a string, not 'all'.

You can try to do this way:

```
mkcp() {
    # last argument is destination
    dir="${@: -1}"
    # create directory if does not exist
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    
    # loop over all arguments
    for file in "$@"
    do
        if [[ "${file}" == "*" ]]; then
            LIST_FILE=$(ls $dir)
            for i in $LIST_FILE
            do
               cp $i $dir
            done
            break
        fi
        # if file is last argument (directory) then break loop
        if [ file == "$dir" ]; then
            break
        fi
        # else keep copying files
        cp -R "$file" "$dir"
    done
}
```

If you need to 'debug' what the script is executing, try to run the script as:

bash -x mkcp * ~/desktop/testdir

The -x will how each step of the script.

Comment: Hi, I copied your code and ran the command `bash -x mkcp * ~/desktop/testdir` but I am getting error:  `bash: mkcp: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think in your code `LIST_FILE=$(ls $dir)` will be `LIST_FILE=$(ls .)` since we are copying all files from the current directory. I might be wrong but it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @maryf, no, the shell will expand the `*` **before** launching the function. See [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) in the manual, and read the Filename Expansion section.