# What are the special dollar sign shell variables?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, dollar-sign

In Bash, there appear to be several variables which hold special, consistently-meaning values. For instance,

```
./myprogram &; echo $!
```

will return the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of the process which backgrounded `myprogram`. I know of others, such as `$?` which I think is the current TTY. Are there others?

Comment: Several of them are not Bash-only. They're also used in other Bourne-related shells and in fact are specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02).

Comment: What about: IFS=$'\n' See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n

Comment: @sgu That's not a parameter; that's a special type of quoting. `$'\n'` is a literal newline character that result from replacing the digraph `\n` with ASCII 10.

Comment: If you came here looking for `${1}`, `${*}`, etc, the braces are just for disambiguation, and often redundant. In isolation, `${x}` is exactly equivalent to `$x`.

Comment: for `$IFS` see [What is the exact meaning of `IFS=$'\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128235/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-ifs-n/66942306#66942306)

Comment: `$?` is not the `TTY` - it is the return value of the last executed command.`tty` is the simple command for it.

Answer (score 1662, accepted):

- `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ... are the [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html).
- `"$@"` is an array-like construct of all positional parameters, `{$1, $2, $3 ...}`.
- `"$*"` is the IFS expansion of all positional parameters, `$1 $2 $3 ...`.
- `$#` is the number of positional parameters.
- `$-` current options set for the shell.
- `$$` pid of the current shell (not subshell).
- `$_` most recent parameter (or the abs path of the command to start the current shell immediately after startup).
- `$IFS` is the (input) field separator.
- `$?` is the most recent foreground pipeline exit status.
- `$!` is the PID of the most recent background command.
- `$0` is the name of the shell or shell script.

Most of the above can be found under [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) in the Bash Reference Manual. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Variables.html) are all the environment variables set by the shell.

For a comprehensive index, please see the [Reference Manual Variable Index](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Variable-Index.html).

Comment: They are all documented in the `bash` man page. The only oddity is that `$_` is only mentioned in the context of its use in the `MAILPATH` variable.

Comment: @chepner look in `man(1) bash` under *Special Parameters* for the rest of the definition of `$_`.

Comment: I use `!$` instead of `$_` in bash scripts, because the latter sometimes fails.

Comment: @amc: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271659/vs-last-argument-of-the-preceding-command-and-output-redirection for differences between `!$` and `$_`.

Comment: see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984958/what-does-it-mean-in-shell-when-we-put-a-command-inside-dollar-sign-and-parenthe) for a discussion on `$(...)` operations

Comment: What is the variable for the PID of the last command, not background?

Comment: @Timo how can you ask the shell for a pid if the command is not in the background?

Comment: @kojiro, thanks, with history, used in [atop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146314/72988). But it stores it in a file, so there is no `$..` variable.

Comment: `$$` doubles up as a good random number generator! Well, sort of random.

Comment: is there any difference where you used double inverted comas? I am referring to `"$@"` and `"$*"`.

Comment: @kojiro Oups, I got it mixed up the the wrong way round. I have deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 53):

- `$_` last argument of last command
- `$#` number of arguments passed to current script
- `$*` / `$@` list of arguments passed to script as string / delimited list

off the top of my head. Google for bash special variables.

Comment: "I did. They sent me here."  -- Bookshop skit     (official doc: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

Comment: I think `$@` is the string and `$*` is the delimited list (according to the above accepted answer, anyways).

Comment: @RastaJedi: `"$@"` expands to a list, `"$*"` expands to a single string. The special behavior of `$@` applies when it's within double quotes.

Comment: Downvoted because this is not a very complete or helpful answer. Saying "Google it" shows a lack of effort, especially considering that the vast majority of people end up here from Google search. I think the least you could do is add links to official documentation. TBH, the only reason I didn't flag it for deletion was because it is at least a _partial_ answer to the question. I know it's old, but please consider editing it to provide more detail.

Answer (score 27):

To help understand what `$#`, `$0` and `$1`, ..., `$n` do, I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<=$#; i++)); do
  echo "parameter $i --> ${!i}"
done
```

Running it returns a representative output:

```
$ ./myparams.sh "hello" "how are you" "i am fine"
parameter 0 --> myparams.sh
parameter 1 --> hello
parameter 2 --> how are you
parameter 3 --> i am fine
```

Comment: What does the !i mean in your for loop? That's actually why I'm here and I can't find an answer anywhere because I don't know what to call it.

Comment: @Anthony this is called [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). You can find a good explantion of his usage in [bash: indirect expansion, please explain?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8515492/1983854).

Answer (score 4):

Take care with some of the examples; $0 may include some leading path as well as the name of the program. Eg save this two line script as ./mytry.sh and the execute it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "parameter 0 --> $0" ; exit 0
```

Output:

```
parameter 0 --> ./mytry.sh
```

This is on a current (year 2016) version of Bash, via Slackware 14.2

Comment: Whether $0 does include a path or not depends on how you ran the script in the first place.  If you executed "./mytry.sh"  that's what you will see in $0.  If you entered "~/mytry.sh" you will see the full path (because the shell will have expanded ~).  If you did ". mytry.sh" you will see 'bash'.