# Linux: what does echo $! in Linux?

Tags: shell

Can anyone tell me what does echo $! mean and how it comes(meaning of '$' and '!')?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollarsign-variables-possibly-bash-only

Comment: man bash... look for `special parameters`

Comment: It's not in "Linux". I guess tou mean `bash` or another shell. The `$!` thing can also be used on bash on an proprietary Unix.

Comment: ...or in any POSIX-compliant shell, not just bash.

Comment: @Vertexwahn, ...btw, editing old posts does have the effect of bringing them back to the front page; something to consider when evaluating the value of a trivial edit, particularly to a question that consensus has determined to be off-topic.

Answer (score 31):

`$!` PID of last job running in background.