# Upstart node.js working directory

Tags: node.js, relative-path, upstart, working-directory

Starting Node.js with Upstart, when trying to access files within Node.js it cannot access them without using the full path. I need it to use the working directory.

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
        echo $$ > /var/run/mynodeapp.pid
        exec sudo -u mynodeapp node server.js >> /var/log/mynodeapp.sys.log 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
        echo "Starting" >> /var/log/mynodeapp.sys.log
end script

pre-stop script
        rm /var/run/mynodeapp.pid
        echo "Stopping" >> /var/log/mynodeapp.sys.log
end script
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is to change directory within the script. In my case, the user is mynodeapp and the node files are in the users directory (/home/mynodeapp/).

```
script
        chdir /home/mynodeapp/
        echo $$ > /var/run/mynodeapp.pid
        exec sudo -u mynodeapp node server.js >> /var/log/mynodeapp.sys.log 2>&1
end script
```

I have yet to find out what $$ means on the echo line or 2>&1. Maybe somebody could chime in with this if they know!

Comment: Have a look here for what $$ is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables

Comment: It says I can in 2 days :-/

Comment: Why do you need to manage your own logging and saving pids?
Upstart manages that for you.
Take a look at `/var/log/upstart/mynodeapp.log` and `status cws-frontend` command.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `chdir` stanza as per the Upstart docs: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#chdir