# Dollar character before double quotes in Bash

Tags: bash

I recently read some bash code, `echo $"asdf"`, what is `$` for?

What is the difference between `$"asdf"` and just `"asdf"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables) and [What does it mean to have a $“dollarsign-prefixed string” in a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script)

Answer (score 12):

As documented in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Locale-Translation.html), it is used for localization:

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign (‘$’) will cause the
>   string to be translated according to the current locale. If the
>   current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the
>   string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

Comment: Could you give an example demonstrating when this actually has an influence on the outcome?

Comment: wow I just learned something new today, it's a good day (+1) :)

Comment: @Alfe, the setup is quite complex. It uses gettext in the background. This link to the Bash manual makes it easy to see the next section, too, where some more details are explained.

Comment: @Palec There is no “next” section after the chapter the link points to.  Just a “previous” and an “up”.  (And the up→next is “comments”.)

Comment: ‍♂️ Sorry, forgot to post the link, @Alfe. Here it is: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation

Comment: Oh, yeah.  That’s really complex.  I didn’t go through it all but thanks for the pointer to how it *would* be used! :-)