# How does this bash code detect an interactive session?

Tags: bash, shell

Following some issues with scp (it did not like the presence of the bash bind command in my `.bashrc` file, apparently), I followed the advice of a clever guy on the Internet (I just cannot find that post right now) that put at the top of its `.bashrc` file this:

```
[[ ${-#*i} != ${-} ]] || return
```

in order to make sure that the bash initialization is NOT executed unless in interactive session.

Now, that works. However, I am not able to figure how it works. Could you enlighten me?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1284631), the `$-` is the current options set for the shell and I know that the `${}` is the so-called "substring" syntax for expanding variables.

However, I do not understand the `${-#*i}` part. And why `$-#*i` is not the same as `${-#*i}`.

Comment: Note that a much simpler equivalent would be `[[ $- = *i* ]]`. Instead of trying to remove a prefix ending in "i" and comparing to the original, you can just check if the original matches the pattern `*i*` (anything, followed by "i", followed by anything else).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> ${parameter#word}
> ${parameter##word}
> ```
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. If the pattern matches the
>   beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the
>   expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>   matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the
>   ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied
>   to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

So basically what happens in `${-#*i}` is that `*i` is expanded, and if it matches the beginning of the value of `$-`, then the result of the whole expansion is `$-` with the shortest matching pattern between `*i` and `$-` deleted.

**Example**

```
VAR="baioasd";
echo ${VAR#*i};
```

outputs `oasd`.

**In your case**

If shell is interactive, `$-` will contain the letter 'i', so when you strip the variable `$-` of the pattern `*i` you will get a string that is different from the original `$-` ( `[[ ${-#*i} != ${-} ]]` yelds true).
If shell is not interactive, `$-` does not contain the letter 'i' so the pattern `*i` does not match anything in `$-` and `[[ ${-#*i} != $- ]]` yelds false, and the `return` statement is executed.

Comment: Although you found the good reference, I think it is good to explain a little bit the particular case of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

[See this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html):

> To determine within a startup script whether or not Bash is running interactively, test the value of the ‘-’ special parameter. It contains i when the shell is interactive

Your substitution removes the string up to, and including the `i` and tests if the substituted version is equal to the original string. They will be different if there is `i` in the `${-}`.