# what does $# -eq in shell mean

Tags: shell

I am new to shell script, in below shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
PREFIX=${PREFIX-/usr/local}
VERSIONS_DIR=$PREFIX/n/versions

test -d $VERSIONS_DIR || mkdir -p $VERSIONS_DIR

if test $# -eq 0; then
```

what does `$# -eq 0` mean in this shell script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Comment: Welcome to shell scripting!  You can use the `man` (manual) command to find help for all of the shell built-in commands.  You can use `man sh` to understand how the shell interprets `$#`, or `man test` for information about the `test` command itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$# = number of arguments. Answer is 3
$@ = what parameters were passed. Answer is 1 2 3
$? = was last command successful. Answer is 0 which means 'yes'
```

Answer (score 2):

The manpage for `test` explains -eq:

```
 n1 -eq n2     True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal.
```

So test will look at the expression before and after the -eq and check if they are equal.

As you mentioned in the answer, $# is the number of arguments to the script, so if you ran

```
./your_script.sh foo bar
```

$# would be 2

Putting it together, that clause (test $# -eq 0) returns true if you didn't run the script with any arguments