# What does the if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ] mean?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my Oracle Linux box, I found a block of script in `/etc/profile` that is hard to figure out:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
        fi
    fi
done
```

My question is the variables in the if statement `${-#*i}` and `$-`.
What does that mean? And why should add an else statement to redirect output?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$-` is a [variable which stores the current options set by the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1608708).

`${-#*i}` is using substring removal to remove the shortest match to the pattern `*i` from the beginning of the variable. So if `$-` has the value `abcifOO` then `${-#*i}` would be `fOO`. [(You can read more about bash substrings here.)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

This means that the test

```
[ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]
```

will be true if the variable `$-` contains the option `i`, which means [interactive mode](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html) is switched on.

All together this means that the output will only be redirected to `/dev/null` if you are in interactive mode.

Answer (score 4):

It's checking whether the shell is interactive. The current shell's options are in `$-` and if removing anything followed by `i` yields a different result, it means that `i` was among the flags.

This would be a lot more readable and idiomatic, though:

```
case $- in *i* ) ... ;; esac
```

Also, it would be better to do the check once, outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

> What does `$-` mean?

From the manual:

> `-`
>
> (A hyphen.) Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set builtin command, or those set by the shell
>   itself (such as the `-i` option).

When you're running `bash` *interactively*, then `$-` might exapnd to something like:

```
himBH
```

When you're executing a script, `$-` wouldn't have `i` (apart from some other flags above).

> What does `${-#*i}` mean?

Saying `${-#*i}` causes the shortest match of `*i` from the beginning of the expansion of `$-` to be deleted.  (Refer to [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

In short, the inner `if` conditional in the example implies that while in the interactive mode the following is executed:

```
. "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and in the non-interactive mode, the following:

```
. "$i"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up a little more detail about $-. if you try to type in your terminal

```
[root@zee ~]# echo $-
himBH
```

Those appear to be shell 'set' values

Snippets from `info bash --index-search=set`

```
 '-h'
```

Locate and remember (hash) commands as they are looked up for
execution. This option is enabled by default.

```
 '-m'
```

Job control is enabled (*note Job Control::).

```
 '-B'
```

The shell will perform brace expansion (*note Brace
Expansion::). This option is on by default.

```
'-H'
```

Enable '!' style history substitution (*note History
Interaction::). This option is on by default for interactive
shells.

Using `+' rather than`-' causes these options to be turned off.
The options can also be used upon invocation of the shell.