# Terminate program after X seconds Linux C

Tags: c, linux, timer, timeout

How can I shut down a linux program in C. I'm editing a script to have a timer thing where the script only runs for 10 seconds then shuts down.

The line I'm running is:
./startmerge

It's a C code to merge all my server files together that I downloaded, but I only want it to be running for 10 seconds.

Comment: A common method is to use a watch dog timer, running as another process. When your script starts, save the PID generated -- then have your watch dog keep an eye on that, sending the kill signal if needed.

Comment: What do you want to happen if it hasn't finished what it's supposed to do within 10 seconds?

Comment: `alarm(10)` is pretty simple though it may not be the way your really want to go.  Note you will need to write a little signal handler for it because the default disposition is to terminate the process.

Answer (score 3):

If most of the time is spent in computing with the CPU (in other words, if the 10 seconds in `./startmerge` are not spent on IO) then you want to limit the CPU time, so use the [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall with `RLIMIT_CPU`. In bash, you want to use its `ulimit` builtin (calling `setrlimit` syscall), see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/220064), like

```
  ulimit -t 10
```

before running `startmerge`.

If your `startmerge` is not CPU intensive, you want to `kill` it after 10 seconds, perhaps (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/841108))

```
  startmerge & ; pidof_startmerge=$!
  sleep 10; kill $pidof_startmerge
```

Better yet, make that a loop (e.g. loop ten times around a `sleep 1`)

If you have access to the C source code of `startmerge` and want to improve it, read first [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). As [Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63743/duck) commented, consider [alarm(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) or [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) or [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and set up a signal handler -e.g. for `SIGALRM` with [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) (but don't forget that signal handlers are limited to calling *async-signal-safe* functions only; you could set a global `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable in them, and test that variable outside). If your `startmerge` has some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) based upon some multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the old `select(2)`) it should even be simpler, and the Linux specific [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) could be very helpful.

You could trap `SIGALRM` in bash, see [this](http://www.woodwose.net/thatremindsme/2011/05/forking-parallel-processes-in-bash/).

[Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) has some chapters related to your question. [Advanced Bash Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) is also useful to read.