# How to check if there is a parameter provided in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, arguments, echo

I wanted to see if there is a parameter provided. But i don't know why this code wont work. What am i doing wrong?

```
   if ![ -z "$1" ]
   then
        echo "$1"
   fi
```

Comment: It would be easier to read if you use `if [ -n "$1" ]`. However, it is best if you use `$#` which returns the number of parameters.

Comment: Also, consider using `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` - `[[ ... ]]` is more robust and has more features; ergo: `[[ ! -z $1 ]]` or `[[ -n $1 ]]` (you can, but don't have to double-quote `$1` when using `[[ ... ]]` in these cases).

Answer (score 17):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
In file line 1:
if ![ -z "$1" ]
    ^-- SC1035: You need a space here.
```

In other words:

```
if ! [ -z "$1" ]
then
     echo "$1"
fi
```

If, as per your comment, it still doesn't work and you happen to be doing this from a function, the function's parameters will mask the script's parameters, and we have to pass them explicitly:

```
In file line 8:
call_it
^-- SC2119: Use call_it "$@" if function's $1 should mean script's $1.
```

Comment: I tend to write `[ ! -z "$1" ]`, but I guess that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Cheers this removed the error but its still not printing the argument given and i dont know why

Comment: @tash517 are you doing it from a function by any chance?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes i am!

Comment: If you are using it on a function, `$1` in the function refers to the parameters passed to the function, not the parameters to the shell script.

Comment: @alvits oh! no wonder nothings being printed out. How do i make it so it is read from the function then?

Comment: @tash517 You can pass all the parameters received by the shell script to the function by passing "$@" when calling the function. Let's pretend your function is `call_it()`. You'll call it like `call_it "$@"`.

Answer (score 5):

You could check the number of given parameters. `$#` represents the number of parameters - or the length of the array containing the parameters - passed to a script or a function. If it is zero then no parameters have been passed. Here is a good read about [positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) in general.

```
$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "No parameters provided"
else
    echo "Number of parameters is $#"
fi
```

Result:

```
$ ./script
No parameters provided
$ ./script first
Number of parameters is 1
$ ./script first second
Number of parameters is 2
```

If you would like to check the parameters passed to the script with a function then you would have to provide the script parameters to the function:

```
$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_checkParameters()
{
    if (( $1 == 0 )); then
        echo "No parameters provided"
    else
        echo "Number of parameters is $1"
    fi
}

_checkParameters $#
```

This will return the same results as in the first example.

Also related: [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Comment: +1 This answer lets you distinguish between *no* first argument (`my-command`) and an explicit empty string as the first argument (`my-command ""`).