# What Does $* Do

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to modify a shell script that isn't very well documented.  I know the basics, but this snippet is confusing.

I am not sure what this line does:

```
time java -showversion -jar ${here_dir}/AESampleTool.jar -f $FILES -d ${output_dir} $*
```

I don't know what $* is. Google doesn't have much. Does the above line set $* equal to what is before it? The next line in the script is $* is passed as a parameter to a function called launch:

```
launch $* 1>$log_file 2>&1
```

Below is the function. The weird part is it seems to be a circular reference. inside the function is what sets $* but then that is passed as a parameter to the function itself.

```
function launch {
hset -x
USER=$AEX_USER
l_output_dir=$output_dir
l_here_dir=$here_dir
l_LOGFILE=$LOGFILE
l_FILES=$FILES
l_EXE_JAR=$EXE_SH
l_AEX_LOGDIR=$AEX_LOGDIR
l_AEX_LOGNAME=$AEX_LOGNAME
time java -showversion -jar ${here_dir}/AESampleTool.jar -f $FILES -d ${output_dir} $*
rc=$?
}
```

Comment: Did you try the man page?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$*` means all arguments, but it's the wrong way to pass them on because it will either split them on whitespace if unquoted (like here) or combine them into a single argument if quoted. It's better to use `"$@"`, which will pass them along in a whitespace-safe manner.

Comment: thanks. I didn't write the original script.  I will make the change though.

Answer (score 1):

`$*`, and `$@` are all related to all the arguments to the shell, but they do different things.

When **unquoted**, `$*` and `$@` do the same thing. They treat each word (sequence of non-whitespace) as a separate argument.

When **quoted** they are quite different. `"$*"` treats the argument list as a single space-separated string, whereas `"$@"` treats the arguments almost exactly as they were when specified on the command line.

Comment: Ok.... so the shell script is calling launch() with all the arguments it was passed, and the ine inside the launch function that calls java is passing all the arguments that launch() received to the java .jar file?  Is that right?