# Trying to read string "$$" from command line arguments

Tags: c++, string, char, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to get a string from the command line arguments, one of the arguments I'm trying to use is `"$$"`. The argument resides in `argv[2]`.

My program reads `"$"` fine `(argv[2] = "$")`, but when `"$$"` is used, `argv[2] = "29628"`....

- What's going on here?

Comment: Bash expansion of $$ ? Try echo $$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$$` returns the process ID (pid) of the current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/3425536).

Use a backslash to escape it: `\$$`.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I'll accept this in a couple mins (can't do it yet)