# How to write a bash alias for `cd` that also `ls` the directories contents after?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Basically, how to make this two step process:

```
$:/ cd Users
$:/Users ls
user1 user2 user3
```

A one step process:

```
$/ cd Users
$:/Users
user1 user2 user3
```

The pseudo code for the bash script could be :

```
after changing directories, pause the input state and take another command
command('ls')
```

**edit**
*Here is a great bash reference - http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml#scripting*

**edit-2** http://bhami.com/rosetta.html

**edit-3** [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16106/how-can-i-create-an-alias-for-cd-and-ls

Comment: It is not very clear what your alias should do that normal `cd` doesn't. Besides, aliases are deprecated in favour of functions.

Comment: @n.m. `cd` doesn't display the contents of the new directory.

Comment: You said it should not display the contents of the new directory right away, but pause and take another command, and only then execute `ls`. It is not very clear what exactly you mean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate to http://askubuntu.com/q/16106/419557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alias mycd='cd $(history 1 | sed "s/.*mycd \(.*\)/\1/") && ls #'
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly. For `mycd somedir`, it expands to `cd somedir && ls somedir` and complains about `somedir` not existing. Neat idea with the history manipulation, though.

Comment: This is the desired behavior when somedir not exists.

Comment: No, I don' think it is: if `somedir` exists, your command does `cd somedir` into it and then issue `ls somedir` instead of just `ls`. DV not from me, btw.

Comment: Or you can flip it around: `alias mycd='ls $(history 1 | sed "s/.*mycd \(.*\)/\1/") && cd\'` so you don't have unexpected behaviour by commenting out the rest of the line.

Comment: Seriously, why do you need to fiddle with aliases and history to produce some broken code, while just this is robust (and is portable)? `mycd() { cd "$@" && ls; }`.

Comment: That works! Very cool...I'll need to locate a bash reference to decode : )