# Get confused about $@ in bash

Tags: bash

First, a simple situation, echo `"$@"` directly in a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -- "First one" "second" "third:one" "" "Fifth: :one"
IFS=:

# IFS=":", using "$@"
c=0
for i in "$@"
do echo "$((c+=1)): [$i]"
done
```

Output, as expected:

```
1: [First one]
2: [second]
3: [third:one]
4: []
5: [Fifth: :one]
```

But when I assign `"$@"` to a variable `var` and then echo `$var` in a for loop, things become complicated:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -- "First one" "second" "third:one" "" "Fifth: :one"
IFS=:

# IFS=":", using $var (var="$@")
var="$@"
c=0
for i in $var
do echo "$((c+=1)): [$i]"
done
```

It Print:

```
1: [First one second third]
2: [one  Fifth]
3: [ ]
4: [one]
```

Why output changed? Can anybody tell me what happened under the hood when I add `var="$@"` and then echo `$var` in a for loop?

Comment: IFS (internal field separator) defines a separator between the fields. In your case it's set to :, therefore you got the output.

Comment: Where do you set var ?

Comment: Have you tried taking few steps back and actually learning bash commands one by one ?

Comment: @OhadM Sorry, my original question is really bad, Now I optimize it.

Comment: @123 Sorry, I missed it in my first revision. Now I add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when running a script, the arguments given on the command line (called *positional parameters*) are available within the script as `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc... The list of positional parameters is contained in the special shell variable `$@` (and also in `$*`). A special property of `$@` is that when quoted (e.g. `"$@"`) it will maintain the quoted relationship of the positional parameters. (e.g. if an argument is given as `"First one"`, `$@` maintains it as a *single* argument as opposed to two)

However, there is also a method for setting positional parameters from within the shell script using `set -- var1 var2 var3`, etc..

`IFS` is the Internal Field Separator that controls *word-splitting*. (that is how strings are split into words -- default: `space tab newline`) Changing `IFS=:` causes word-splitting to occur on the `':'` character instead of the default.

So in your case you have new positional parameters `"First one" "second" "third:one" "" "Fifth: :one"` set and if you look at where they will break if split at each `':'` character, you get:

```
"First one second third"
"one  Fifth"
"  "
"one"
```

Mystery solved. This is a good example to teach you about positional parameters and the Internal Field Separator along with its effect on word-splitting. Learn it - it is important is shell scripting.

Comment: An important point is also that with `var="$@"`, you are left with a single string of white-space-separated words; there is no longer any distinction between the space that is part of each parameter and the space that separates two parameters.

Answer (score 2):

from: [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

"$@" is an array-like construct of all positional parameters, {$1, $2, $3 ...}