# What does "$-" mean in bash or zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

Today I found that variable '$-' is a random string, but I don't know what it stands for.

```
➜  ~ echo $-
569JNRTXZghikms
```

And I can't change the value:

```
➜  ~ -='sss'
zsh: command not found: -=sss
➜  ~
```

And, in a docker it was:

```
➜  ~ docker  run --rm -ti ubuntu          
root@7084255fd54e:/# echo $-
himBH
```

Or:

```
➜  ~ docker  run --rm -ti alpine ash
/ # echo $-
smi
```

Does it's value related to the system?

Comment: Explained with an example, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#EX34

Comment: You can change what is reported by changing the shell options with `set`.

Comment: You have tagged the question `bash` but you are obviously using `zsh`. Docker is using `bash`, and that's why the string is different. Please edit the tags to the correct value.

Comment: Thank you all. Now I got it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This question is asking about zsh. I do not believe that it is an exact duplicate of the one you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$-` current options set for the shell.

From [the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

> Using ‘+’ rather than ‘-’ causes these options to be turned off. The
>   options can also be used upon invocation of the shell. The current set
>   of options may be found in $-.
>
> The remaining N arguments are positional parameters and are assigned,
>   in order, to $1, $2, … $N. The special parameter # is set to N.
>
> The return status is always zero unless an invalid option is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

`$-` gives you the current options set for the shell.

See the accepted answer from this question for the various other special dollar variables available:

[What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using zsh, run this command:

```
LESS=+/'PARAMETERS SET BY THE SHELL' man zshparam
```

to find:

> - <S>  Flags supplied to the shell on invocation or by the set or setopt commands.

---

For bash (from Docker), run this command:

```
LESS=+/'^ *Special Parameters' man bash
```

To read:

> - Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set builtin command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option).