# What does "$!" mean?

Tags: bash, shell

I have some bash shell script code

```
#!/bin/bash
var=""
something happens here
var=$!
```

I could't find anyting about it and I'm not sure if it makes any sense but if so - what does it mean?

Thanks.

EDIT: Wow - looks like I didn't search deep enough - the answer lies hier [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Comment: Read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash

Comment: Thx. I even found this https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html and I'm not sure why I didn't found it in the first place. Oh boy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$!` resolves to the process id of the latest process run in the background.