# Passing an object property to bash script using java

Tags: java, bash, swing, jfilechooser, processbuilder

Currently I am trying to create a desktop application using Swing's file chooser that will convert a specific type of file to another one, making use of cygwin. The relevant code part is :

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe", "/cygdrive/c/Users/orhun.vatansever/workspace/extchangegui/src/extchangegui/dene.sh"};
                Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

which is working fine, but since the content of my bashscript is like

```
cd "${0%/*}"
java -jar xyz.jar aegis.xyz
```

This means my code is working for one specific xyz file, what I want to do is select the file and run the command on that specific xyz file. I can get the filename with myfile.getName(), however I don't know how to use this data, where to put it in process builder. I see two solutions I think, one is setting one of the process builder parameters(don't know which one) to "java -jar xyz.jar "+file.getName()"" , other is changing the script's content upon clicking the open button of file chooser(which doesn't make sense I think).

Comment: Is there a reason you're running your script in a terminal (which will show up as a window on your screen)?  You can run "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe" instead and it will not create a window.

Comment: I want the user to browse the file, there may be many xyz files and the user might want to select a specific one

Comment: OK, that makes sense then

Answer (score 0):

You can add the name string to your command array and reference it as a [*positional parameter*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/261156) in your script. Say `cmd[2] = "xyz"`,

```
 java -jar ${2}.jar aegis.${2}
```

> That's not what I want to do…I want to…get its name via `file.getName()` property, and somehow pass it to the script, or run it like `java -jar xyz.jar + chosenFile.getName()`

Then pass the file name in the command string, `cmd[2] = file.getName()`,

```
 java -jar xyz.jar ${2}
```

You should also consider using [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create your `Process`.

Comment: that's not what I want to do,what I want to do is being able to pass the chosen file and get its name via file.getName() property, and somehow pass it to the script, or run it like "java -jar xyz.jar "+chosenFile.getName()"" ,

Comment: but isn't file a java object and getName()  a java property, are they preserved when I run them in my script?

Comment: I tried what you said, it did not return any error however it also did not generate the folder as it should

Comment: Add `echo ${2}` to your script to see what's coming through.