# Is it possible to "dump" all of the bash special variables via a command, like env?

Tags: bash, special-variables

```
#!/bin/bash
env
```

This spits out a bunch of environment variables.  $0, $@, $_, etc. are not output.  Is there a way to dump them out, similar to how `env` or `set` dumps the rest of the environment?  I don't mean anything like `echo $0` or something, I want to see all of the possible special variables in their current state without directly calling all of them.

Comment: I am aware I can enumerate them myself.  My point is I would like a function to do so.  I could write `dump_vars` or something to do so, but I'm wanting to know if such a thing already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in variables are included in the output to the `set` command. (`$0` and `$@` aren't variables at all, even special ones, so they aren't included -- but `$_`, `$BASH_ALIASES`, `$BASH_SOURCE`, `$BASH_VERSINFO`, `$DIRSTACK`, `$PPID`, and all the other things that *are* built-in variables are present).

`$0`, `$*`, `$@`, etc. are not built-in variables; they are *special parameters* instead. Semantics are quite different (you can use `declare -p` to print a variable's value, but not that of a special parameter; many built-in variables lose their special behavior if reassigned, whereas special parameters can never be the target of an assignment; etc).

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars covers both built-in variables and special parameters.

---

If your goal is to generate a log of current shell state, I suggest the following:

```
(set; set -x; : "$0" "$@") &>trace.log
```

`set` dumps the things that are *actually* built-in variables (including `$_`), and the `set -x` log of running `: "$0" "$@"` will contain enough information to reproduce all special parameters which are based on your positional parameters (`"$*"`, `"$@"`, etc); whereas the output from `set` will include all other state.

Comment: Speaking of semantics, an old name for shell variables was *named parameters*.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no existing function to automatically do this.  You'll have to enumerate the variables yourself--but that's easy because there are only a few: [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Comment: The question asked here is, "Is there a function that enumerates the special variables," not "What are the special variables?"

Comment: As for "downvoting instead of fixing the link" -- this was originally effectively a link-only answer. Changing the link would be tantamount to completely rewriting the answer. The downvote was removed as soon as you corrected the link (even though I don't read the new one as on-topic for the OP's question either, it's at least not full of inaccuracies).