# Concept of $argv[1] and $1

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, argv

What is the difference between `$argv[1]` and `$1`?
`$argv[1]` and `$argv[$1]`, which is correct?

I tried the below codes and obtained the outputs as mentioned below:

1)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The user $1 is logged on to the system on"
```

Run as: `bash logs.sh home`

Output: `The user home is logged on to the system on`

2)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The user $argv[1] is logged on to the system on"
```

Run as: `bash logs.sh home`

Output: `The user [1] is logged on to the system on`

3)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The user $argv[$1] is logged on to the system on"
```

Run as: `bash logs.sh home`

Output: `The user [home] is logged on to the system on`

Please clarify these.

Comment: Why is this tagged `linux-kernel`? `bash` also runs on other operating systems

Comment: There is no variable named `argv` in bash/shell, and your tests just expose that. (In your tests replace `$argv` with an *empty string*, and the results will be consistent).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163144/608639)

Answer (score 0):

In case of bash, I usually say, play with it:

```
> echo $argv[1]
[1]
> argv=blabla
> echo $argv[1]
blabla[1]
```

The token `$argv[1]` is parsed as `$argv` and `[1]`. The `$argv` is expanded into the variable `argv` value, and `[1]` is left as it is. To access an array  by the index, use `{}`, ex. `${argv[1]}`. As you can also see, arrays in bash are indexed from zero:

```
> argv=(1 2 3)
> echo ${argv[1]}
2
```

The variable `argv` is no special name for a variable in bash, it has no special meaning and doesn't have any coleration with positional arguments passed to script. To access arguments use `$1` to access first argument, `$2` to access the second, use `"$@"` to expand parameters each to separate word, `"$*"` expands parameters to a single word and `$#` get's the count of arguments.

The `$argv[$1]` has also no special meaning at all. As `argv` variable is not set, the `$argv` is expanded into nothing. The first parameter to your script is `home` so `$1` expands to `home`. The `[` `]` have no special meaning outside `${ ... }` braces. The `[` and `]` are left untouched. So `$argv[$1]` is expanded like

```
`$argv` + `[` + `$1` + `]`
`` + `[` + `home + `]`
`[home]`
```

You can test `$1` variables with simple functions:

```
> f() { echo $# 1:$1 2:$2 3:$3; }
> f home 
1 1:home 2: 3:
> f home kamil salini
3 1:home 2:kamil 3:salini
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is anything wrong with this answer? (except my bad english, sorry for it...)