# What is the equivalent to Bash's exec $@ in Python?

Tags: python, bash

Some bash scripts end their execution with `exec "$@"`, often invoking a series of commands before finally replacing their execution with the arguments passed initially to the script.

If you were to write a Python script to replace that bash script, what would the final command be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In bash,

> "$@" is an array-like construct of all positional parameters, {$1, $2,
>   $3 ...}.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1420079

So `exec "$@"` would invoke all of the additional positional parameters, with the first argument being the program name, and then subsequent arguments being the arguments to that replacement program.

In Python, `sys.argv` (from the `sys` module) is...

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Replacing the current running process with another is a job for the `os.exec*` family of functions (unsurprisingly, from the `os` module), see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvp

If Bash's `exec` is invoked without the `-c` flag, it inherits the environment of the current process, and also uses the `$PATH` variable to look up the program to execute if the path isn't absolute.

As such, the closest `exec*` function is `os.execvp` (**v**ariable number of arguments, using **p**ath). Also to bare in mind is...

> The various exec* functions take a list of arguments for the new
>   program loaded into the process. In each case, the first of these
>   arguments is passed to the new program as its own name rather than as
>   an argument a user may have typed on a command line. For the C
>   programmer, this is the argv[0] passed to a program’s main(). For
>   example, os.execvp('/bin/echo', ['foo', 'bar']) will only print bar on
>   standard output; foo will seem to be ignored.

---

So, I would implement Bash's `exec "$@"` in Python as follows (assuming `os` and `sys` are imported):

```
os.execvp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[1:])
```

This isn't a perfect replication, Bash's exec will handle no arguments as a no-op, while this code will throw an `IndexError`.