# What are the special dollar sign variables in zsh?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, zsh, dollar-sign

When using `bash`, there are self-referential variables that don't seem to be available in `zsh`. For example, `$?` gets the exit status of the most recent foreground process, `$_` gets the last parameter of the previous command, etc.

Are there equivalents to these in `zsh`? I ask with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables) for bash.

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [Variables Index](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Variables-Index.html), [Parameters Set By The Shell](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell). I think `$argv[1]` is the equivalent of `$1` and `$_` is the same, but I'm not a zsh expert.

Comment: `$1`, `$2` exist in `zsh`. They're required by POSIX.

Comment: @Bamar good point, I changed the example

Comment: `$?` should work, too. `zsh` should implement all the standard POSIX variables.

Comment: And so does `$_`, although it's not required by POSIX.

Comment: You can find all the POSIX special variables at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02

Comment: Here is the command I'm trying to run: `command -v python3.7 &> /dev/null; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo "Python version $_ is currently installed."; else echo "Python version $_ is NOT installed."; fi`. The final print statement runs but the `$_` variable displays nothing (whereas in `bash` it does display correctly).

Answer (score 3):

`bash` calls these the special parameters (to distinguish them from ordinary variables and the positional parameters). `zsh` implements essentially the same set, but documents them along with other parameters set by the shell, though it does also tag each one as special.

See `man zshparam`:

```
PARAMETERS SET BY THE SHELL
       In the parameter lists that follow, the mark `<S>' indicates  that  the
       parameter  is  special.   `<Z>'  indicates  that the parameter does not
       exist when the shell initializes in sh or ksh emulation mode.

       The following parameters are automatically set by the shell:

       ! <S>  The process ID of the last command  started  in  the  background
              with &, or put into the background with the bg builtin.

       # <S>  The  number of positional parameters in decimal.  Note that some
              confusion may occur with the syntax  $#param  which  substitutes
              the  length of param.  Use ${#} to resolve ambiguities.  In par-
              ticular, the sequence `$#-...' in an  arithmetic  expression  is
              interpreted as the length of the parameter -, q.v.

       ARGC <S> <Z>
              Same as #.

       $ <S>  The  process  ID  of  this  shell.  Note that this indicates the
              original shell started by invoking  zsh;  all  processes  forked
              from  the  shells  without executing a new program, such as sub-
              shells started by (...), substitute the same value.

       [... etc ...]
```

Comment: Nice to point out the specific entry in the manual