# Can I recursively create files on Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

If I run `touch non/existing/folder/my-file.txt`, touch complains about non-existing folders.

Can I create these folders on the same command, similar to `mkdir -p`?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can write a script that does that:

```sh
# new.sh
for file; do
  [[ $file =~ ((.+\/)*)(.+) ]] && mkdir -p "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  touch $file
done
```

Then run: `./new.sh non/existing/folder/my-file.txt possibly/other/files.txt`

Comment: That should really be `for file in "$@"` (or shorter: just `for file`); your version suffers from word splitting and parameter expansion. `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` should be quoted as well.

Comment: Great suggestions! Is it ok now?

PS: Found a good explanation of shell special variables here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables