# Export changed files & folders from multiple commit

Tags: git

I found a Git command but it only export file names between commit ids and save in a file

> git diff --name-only commitid1 commitid2 > ../result.txt

An example for result.txt:

```
Web/A/Recoverpw.aspx
Web/B/Root.aspx
```

But I want to export them as files in a folder in structure. Example:

```
Web
|__A
   |__Recoverpw.aspx
|__B
   |__Root.aspx
```

Exported files must be lastest, got from local respository. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: "latest" right? But isn't that a vague requirement? assuming by latest you mean the tip of a branch(local) and there could exist multiple branches

Comment: I don't think Git will do this for you. You already have a list of files, look for a way to post-process that into the format you want. Perhaps use the -P option of [tree(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree).

Comment: @hus787, lastest from my local repository, don't take care branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only commands which comes close would be [`git archive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), for which you can specify a list of path you want to export in a (zip or tar) archive, you could un-archive elsewhere.

But that isn't a convenient way to get only the *files* you need.

The other way would be to:

- clone your local repo
- delete all the files *not* listed your `git diff` output

Actually, an easier way would be to copy each file from the `git diff` with their path.
See "[linux: copy and create destination dir if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722721/6309)"

```
cp --parents a/b/c existing_dir
```

> copies the file '`a/b/c`' to '`existing_dir/a/b/c`', creating any missing intermediate directories.

Comment: Note to self: other `cp` alternatives at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947954/how-to-have-the-cp-command-create-any-necessary-folders-for-copying-a-file-to-a

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a VB Script on Windows myself and it runs well.