# In BASH How Can One Recursively Copy Only Content Version-Controlled by Git?

Tags: git, bash, version-control, directory, cp

Is there a way to in a bash terminal mass recursive copy (`cp -rf` equivalent) from one subdirectory to another, preserving the directory structure but ONLY copying files/directories are version controlled by `git`?

The naive strategy would be...

```
cp -rf <targetDir> variantDir/; git add variantDir;
```

... but that would pick up a bunch of files that are data files dropped by the IDE, etc. I'm working with -- files which aren't currently version controlled in `<targetDir>`.

---

As background, I have the following directory structure:

```
${baseDir}/
${baseDir}/variantA
```

Basically, `${baseDir}/` contains all the original version controlled content, and `${baseDir}/variantA` contains the content that differs for a targeted variant.  For the original target folder `${baseDir}/variantA` is ignored.  For the second target the folder `variantA` is included, effectively superceding any content that matches other than the `variantA` part of the path.

i.e. if I had:

```
${baseDir}/someFolder/someStuff.cpp
${baseDir}/variantA/someFolder/someStuff.cpp
```

It would use the second path for the second target, and the first path for the first target.

Now I'm adding `variantB`and it's a full variant (unlike `variantA` that has some fall through to the base target's files).  It's closer to `variantA` so I want to copy over everything in the base folder first, THEN copy over everything in the `variantA` subfolder to the `variantB` subfolder ... that way I have a new copy of all content (including the fall throughs) to version commit, with a preference for `variantA` file versions, when such overlap exists.

I would use the naive snippet above, but I have a more fundamental problem that my IDE has dropped `*.xml` files and other junk that `git` is somehow smart enough to flag as not uncommitted content (probably language specific), but which `cp` would ignore.  I believe `git` would copy these files if EXPLICITLY asked to do, so, hence I want to exclude all the non-`git` controlled content, while using the general strategy stated prior.

Comment: Aren't you kind of re-inventing branching?

Comment: Dir structure is more or less out of my control to some extent for the code base I'm currently working on, but the reasoning behind it sort of makes sense.  Traditional branching is used for some cases, while variant directories with a specialized build system is used to cut down on the redundancy while targeting simultaneously multiple targets... I'm kind of locked in, though, but yea, I get it's a weird case in some regards, but that's why I listed the simple version first as I feel the general question of how to `cp -rf` only version controlled content is pretty ubiquitous.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any tool *other* than `git` (or one specifically designed to work with a Git repository) to be able to do this.

Comment: Why not use the `git archive` command to do this? It can pipe a tarball to its stdout, so pipe that to `tar -x -C /path/to/destination` and you're done.

Comment: I'd imagine the general strategy suggested for `git` controlled repos would also apply to `svn` using equivalent commands.  My current best idea is `git log com/ford/theme/Resources/IconTheme=ford-gen2|wc -l` as that gives `0` for version controlled stuff, but some non-zero number of lines for version controlled stuff... so my working plan was to copy the dir structure, checking w/ that, then copy files only via recursive listing, again checking with that... but that's kind of a clunky way to do it... I was hoping for something more pleasing & smooth.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606955/how-can-i-make-git-show-a-list-of-the-files-that-are-being-tracked has commands to show all tracked files.

Comment: Charles, sounds like a potential solution... I'm unfamiliar with that particular command... so it only `tar`s the version controlled content?

Comment: Correct, it only archives version-controlled content.

Comment: as @Charles said, ```git archive``` is your friend

Comment: Ah, Benjamin that might be even better... agreed I could probably just use that directly... again not a `git` master by any means, so both those usages are new to me.

Comment: Combine `git list-tree ...` with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947954/how-to-have-the-cp-command-create-any-necessary-folders-for-copying-a-file-to-a and you have a simpler strategy than `git archive` as it doesn't rely on intermediates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git ls-files | tar Tc - | tar Cx /path/to/destination
```

this takes what's at your current spot in the worktree.  To use a subdirectory of a commit use the `git archive` solution [@Charles Duffy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143371/in-bash-how-can-one-recursively-copy-only-content-version-controlled-by-git/44144020#comment75304875_44143371),

```
git archive master:path/to/subdir | tar Cx /path/to/destination
```

and to work with your currently-added-but-not-committed content you can subsitute `$(git write-tree)` for `master` above.

Comment: `tar Tc` and `tar Cx` don't work for me. What are the `T` and `C` supposed to do?

Comment: Akk. Dropped an argument.  T is "read a list of files", `C` is "change directory"

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a fresh work tree (which obviously will only have source-controlled files in it since it's generated from source control)?

There are a few ways to do this (with clones or work trees) but I would think

```
git worktree add -b variantB path/where/variantB/will/be/created master
```

would get you started with the relevant files (those under source control).  Then you just copy `path/where/variant/B/will/be/created/variantA` over `path/where/variant/B/will/be/created`

And because of the `-b` option, you're already on a fresh branch - which is how you'll likely want to maintain this variation anyway since it's a full replacement.  (For varientA it's debatable since you want variantA to keep up-to-date with baseline changes to the files it doesn't vary...)

But if you don't want to maintain a new branch for this, no big deal.  Use either a clone or a worktree add command (without `-b`) to create a worktree image of variantB as above, but then move the resulting files into your default worktree under a .../variantB directory

Answer (score 1):

To copy only files under source control from variantA to variantB:

```
cd variantA
rsync --files-from <(git ls-files .) . ../variantB
```

This works by including only files returned by `git ls-files`.

Edit: the `<()` syntax is called [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but I'm on `Mintty` `BASH` which doesn't have `rsync` built in... is there an equivalent w/out it that you'd propose?  `BASH` version is `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release`; `Mintty` version is `2.0.3`

Comment: If this is on Windows, you may not have working process substitutions either. I don't remember if it extends to msys builds, but that functionality was broken on cycgwin builds of bash for a long, long time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `cp`, you can use the `--parents` option:

```
mkdir variantB
cd variantA
cp --parents $(git ls-files .) ../variantB
```

Comment: This will fail badly if any filenames contain spaces or could be interpreted as globs. Much safer to use `git ls-files -z .` and parse the NUL-delimited stream this emits.