# cp : no such file or directory bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, cp

Why is It that I am not able to create a file?
Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(date +"%D")

sudo cp ./script1.sh "$var _script1.txt"
```

It's showing this error:

cp: cannot create regular file '01/23/20 _script1.txt': No such file or directory

I am even using sudo so there's definitely no permission problem.

Comment: There are `/` in the name so the date should be directories but it seems that the directories doesn't exists

Comment: So if you want to create a directory `01` with a subdirectory `23` with a file `20_script1.txt` you'll have to use `mkdir -p` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947954/how-to-have-the-cp-command-create-any-necessary-folders-for-copying-a-file-to-a

Comment: @MickaelB. I just want to create one directory with  slashes ( / )  in it, is it not possible?

Comment: No it's not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename or https://askubuntu.com/questions/719916/how-to-have-a-forward-slash-in-a-file-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date variable contains `/` but you should not have `/` inside a filename. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename)

I would suggest you change your variable to the below format (using `-` instead as separators) :

```
var=$(date +%M-%d-%Y)
```

With this format your copy operation should work

Answer (score 0):

You can't it's prohibited. But you can always use work around.
For example use one of these sign.
( ⟋ ⁄ ∕ ⧸ ⁄ )

```
 mkdir "⧸test"
```